# Loading a class by its name MyClass.class - is this possible?

Tags: java

It is possible to load a class given a String and its name? ie "MyClass.class"

Further, is it possible to pass parameters to the constructor using this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Construct Object using class name](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=113).

Key methods being [`forName()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) and [`newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look up the Reflection API.